# How to make 'Jquery autocomplete' to work in cross domain

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i am using the jquery auto complete script like this

```
$("#ac1").autocomplete('search.php');
```

And it is working (ie i keep the 'search.php' in local machine)

But when i place 'search.php' file in another server (say  *test.com*).

and change the script as

```
$("#ac1").autocomplete('http://www.test.com/search.php');
```

it is not working

Can any one help me to get it work

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916682/jquery-autocomplete-xml-cross-site-request

Comment: That's the same origin policy intervening. You can't make cross-domain Ajax calls.

Comment: @Juhana: ....unless you use a server-side proxy or wrap the data in a function call (JSON-P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you should use JSON-P. The slightly longer answer is here: [jQuery autocomplete - xml cross site request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916682/jquery-autocomplete-xml-cross-site-request)